# open accordion when clicked on a separate image

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I need the following functionality on my page.

there's a set of images sliding from left to right. Each image corresponds to an according below it. (Note that image is NOT part of the accordion. Accordion has its own header and content, the image is separate above it). Initially, no accordion is displayed, when you click on an image the corresponding accordion is to be displayed, and all others to hide). I've used the bootstrap accordion on my page, which works fine on its own, but I'm not sure how to do the part linking that to the image slider.

Also, is there any other alternative than using the accordion here? Please note this should also support touch sliding.

Regards,
Chathu

Answer (score 1):

you can trigger the event on your accordion when user click image on your page

```
$("#accordianID").collapse('toggle');
```

OR

```
$("#accordianID").collapse('show')
```

by this way you can remotely change the state of accordion

Ref:[Bootstrap DOC](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse)

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I think I made a mistake when explaining the issue. Actually, I have a single accordion with several expand/collapse divs in it. and I want the others to 'disappear' rather than 'toggle' when one accordion div is displaying. Is this possible, or do I have to use several accordions?

Answer (score 0):

this is what I do, here are the horizontal bar that act as triggers to display accordions. (I've replaced  with )

```
<ul id="zoneSlider">
        <li class="legacy_slider" style="width: 300px; height: 131px; float: left; display: block; background: #c11e07;">
            <div onclick="OperateAccordion(1)"; class="flex-caption_slider" style="background: #c11e07; height: 131px;">End the wait</div>
        </li>

        <li class="legacy_slider" style="width: 300px; height: 131px; float: left; display: block; background: #ff9400;">
            <div onclick="OperateAccordion(2)"; class="flex-caption_slider" style="background: #ff9400; height: 131px;">Intelligence @ the sales floor</div>
        </li>

        <li class="legacy_slider" style="width: 300px; height: 131px; float: left; display: block; background: #0ea913;">
           <div onclick="OperateAccordion(3)"; class="flex-caption_slider" style="background: #0ea913; height: 131px;">Helping store associates do more with less</div>
        </li>

        <li class="legacy_slider" style="width: 300px; height: 131px; float: left; display: block; background: #00a9ec;">
           <div onclick="OperateAccordion(4)"; class="flex-caption_slider" style="background: #00a9ec; height: 131px;">Let's help save water</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Then I used separate accordions:

```
        <div class="accordion" id="accordion1">
        <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne">END THE WAIT
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse" style="height: 0px;">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
        <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordio2" href="#collapseTwo">END THE WAIT
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse" style="height: 0px;">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion" id="accordion3">
        <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordio3" href="#collapseThree">END THE WAIT
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-body collapse" style="height: 0px;">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

following is the JS I used to control the display:

```
        <script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#accordion2').hide();
            $('#accordion3').hide();
            $('#accordion4').hide();
            $('#accordion5').hide();
        });

        function OperateAccordion(index) {
            if (index == 1) {
                $('#accordion3').hide();
                $('#accordion4').hide();
                $('#accordion5').hide();
                $('#accordion2').show();
            }
            else if (index == 2) {
                $('#accordion2').hide();
                $('#accordion4').hide();
                $('#accordion5').hide();
                $('#accordion3').show();
            }
            else if (index == 3) {
                $('#accordion2').hide();
                $('#accordion3').hide();
                $('#accordion5').hide();
                $('#accordion4').show();
                //$("#accordion3").collapse();
            }
            else if (index == 4) {
                $('#accordion2').hide();
                $('#accordion3').hide();
                $('#accordion4').hide();
                $('#accordion5').show();
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Now this does what I want, except for one thing. The accordion should be exapanded when it's displayed. Right now it's collapsed when it's displayed. How to achieve this?

Also, I'm not sure I'm doing it the best way, so appreciate if you can suggest a better alternative.

Comment: where you hit `.show()` before or after that add `.collapse("show")` for example in your case of `index==1` add `$("#accordion2").collapse("show");`

Answer (score 0):

okay, I partially solved my problem with the following:

```
   $('#accordion2').show();
   $('#collapseOne').collapse('show');
```

But this has a slight problem. In the blink of the eye, it expands, collapse and then expands again. I'm sure it happens because of this show() thing, but can't find a workaround for that.

Comment: add `$('#collapseOne').collapse('show');` before `$('#accordion2').show();`